# Problem with a conditional in a tabular

Tags: tables, conditionals

I want to use conditionals to fill a `tabular`, but it fails. My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\NewEnviron{montab}{%
    \setcounter{mycounter}{0}
    \newcommand{\mcItem}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{mycounter}%

        \ifcase \arabic{mycounter} % If counter = 0
            \relax
        \or % If counter = 1 
      ##1 & % 
        \or % If counter = 2
            ##1 \\%
        \or  % If counter = 3
            ##1 &
        \or  % If counter = 4
            ##1
        \fi
            }
\begin{tabular}{cc}
        \BODY
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{montab}
\mcItem{premier}
\mcItem{deuxieme}
\mcItem{troisieme}
\mcItem{quatrieme}
\end{montab}

\end{document}
```

I hoped with this code to obtain the output :

```
premier    deuxieme
troisieme  quatrieme
```

I think the problem comes from the fact for example that a part of the conditional (the `\ifcase`) is before a `&` and the rest is after it. Since any cell of a `tabular` forms a group, the different elements of the conditional lie in different groups.

1. Did I understand the problem correctly?
2. How to do it better? :)

Answer (score 6):

You can't begin a conditional in one cell and end it in another one:

```
\usepackage{environ}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\NewEnviron{montab}{%
    \setcounter{mycounter}{0}
    \newcommand{\mcItem}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{mycounter}%
        \ifcase \arabic{mycounter} % If counter = 0
        \or
    \expandafter\firstoffour\or % If counter = 1 
        \expandafter\secondoffour\or % If counter = 2
        \expandafter\thirdoffour\or  % If counter = 3
        \expandafter\fourthoffour  % If counter = 4
        \fi
      {##1 &}{##1 \\}{##1 &}{##1}
  }
\begin{tabular}{cc}
        \BODY
\end{tabular}
}
\long\def\firstoffour#1#2#3#4{#1}
\long\def\secondoffour#1#2#3#4{#2}
\long\def\thirdoffour#1#2#3#4{#3}
\long\def\fourthoffour#1#2#3#4{#4}
```

Actually you don't need four cases, but only two, as a final `\\` is good in a tabular.

```
\makeatletter
\newif\iffirstcol
\NewEnviron{montab}{%
  \global\firstcoltrue
  \newcommand\mcItem[1]{%
    \iffirstcol
      \global\firstcolfalse
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \global\firstcoltrue
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi{##1 &}{##1 \\}}%
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \BODY
  \end{tabular}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: "You can't begin a conditional in one cell and end it in another one." Inaccurate: you can't skip over `&` or `\cr` in a tabular, be it with a conditional or delimited-argument macros.  However, `\halign{#\cr\relax\iftrue\cr}\fi` works alright, because it doesn't skip over the `\cr`.

Comment: "Another noteworthy characteristic of this manual is that it doesn't always tell the truth" (The TeXbook, preface). ;-)

Comment: ok, thanks fo the lessen. But, my very first attempt was done with `4 nested `ifthenelse`, instead of `ìfcase`, and this worked. Why ?

Comment: With nested `\ifthenelse` it worked because it's the same concept: resolve the conditionals before producing `&` or `\\`.